# Stop Phonegap from inserting Socket IO

Tags: javascript, cordova

We are building an app and we are using `phonegap serve` to run it as a web app. We also have a mobile version of it.

Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I've learn, phonegap is automatically inserting socket io JS into my `index.html` file. But we already have the socket io included via the `<script></script>` tag. So what happened's now is that we got 2 inclusion of socket io js.

So as for performance speaking, we only need to load the socket io once.

**Screenshot**
https://www.evernote.com/l/AA1k9PiF_bJM3qju6-DeE1ZLwkKV17TVyV8

Comment: Why are you including it in the script tag if on build Cordova/Phonegap inserts it in for you?

Comment: Because we need it when we do an app build. There are some modules of the app that uses socket io

Comment: Cordova does not include socket.io by itself!

Comment: yes it is.. i have tried it even with an newly created project. https://www.evernote.com/l/AA1k9PiF_bJM3qju6-DeE1ZLwkKV17TVyV8